# Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception

Tags: drupal, e-commerce, open-atrium

I am facing same problem as this post.
[drupal views module mysql error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524456/drupal-views-module-mysql-error?answertab=active#tab-top)

I increased max_allowed_packet from 1M to 60M at /opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf but problem is still coming out when I try to add everything at structure. This is the screen code.

Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

Original

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT * FROM {uc_product_classes}; Array ( ) in uc_product_class_load() (line 1704 of /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced-a/sites/all/modules/uc_product/uc_product.module).
```

Additional

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: SELECT ff.* FROM {filter_format} ff WHERE (status = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ORDER BY weight ASC; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] =&gt; 1 ) in filter_formats() (line 407 of /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced-a/modules/filter/filter.module).
```

Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in _drupal_session_write() (line 206 of /opt/lampp/htdocs/advanced-a/includes/session.inc).
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty high setting for max_allowed_packet (almost as if someone had told you to set it to 16 but you heard it as "sixty")

Be that as it may, did you also make the necessary changes to my.ini?

https://drupal.org/files/my.ini_.patch

Answer (score 0):

Change `max_allowed_packet = 1M` to `max_allowed_packet = 16M` in `my.ini`